# How do I configure queue workers, connection and limiter to avoid job failing

Tags: laravel, supervisord, rate-limiting, laravel-queue, laravel-jobs

My Project consumes several 3rd party APIs which enforce requests limiting. My Project calls these api's through Laravel Jobs. I am using using [Spatie/aravel-rate-limited-job-middleware](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-rate-limited-job-middleware) for rate limiting

Once a Project is submitted, around 60 jobs are dispatched on an average. These jobs needs to be executed as  `1 Job/Minute`

There is one supervisord program running 2 process of the default queue with `--tries=3`
also in `config/queue.php` for redis I am using `'retry_after' => (60 * 15)`  to avoid retrying while job is executing.

My current Rate Limiter middleware is coded this way

```
return (new RateLimited())
            ->allow(1)
            ->everySeconds(60)
            ->releaseAfterBackoff($this->attempts());
```

What happens is that 3 jobs get processed in 3 mins, but after that all jobs gets failed.

what I can understand is all jobs are requeued every min and once they cross tries threshold (3), they are moved to failed_jobs.

I tried removing `--tries` flags but that didn't work. I also tried increasing `--tries=20`, but then jobs fails after 20 mins.
I don't want to hardcode the `--tries` flag as in some situation more than 100 jobs can be dispatched.

I also want to increase no of queue workers process in the supervisor so that few jobs can execute parallely.

I understand it is issue with configuring retry, timeouts flags but I don't understand how. Need Help...

Comment: first of all check supervisor log there may be some timeout issue at server end , check the logs of laravel and Server(Apache/Nginx) you can have idea why jobs are failing

Comment: jobs are failing due to max Attempt. All failed jobs are going to failed jobs table.
`Illuminate\Queue\MaxAttemptsExceededException`

Comment: it seems function called inside job is getting error ,that`s why it goes to retry. because usually it should not be retry

Comment: I firmly believe This is issue with rate limiting, as the error is `MaxAttemptsExceededException`. When I disable ratelimiting, everything works fine.
I have tested the jobs carefully. Only thing I don't understand is the flow of how laravel implies ratelimiting through redis.

Comment: have you mentioned maximum tries in supervisor configuration file ?

Comment: Yes, There is one supervisord program running 2 process of the default queue with --tries=3

Comment: In my case i have nt used ratelimited middleware might be this can be solve problem . Try once without middlewere might be got some hint

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230119/discussion-between-shawinder-jit-singh-and-pankaj-jha).